# Overlay many plots with a different range of x

Tags: r, plot

I would like to make a plot like the this image [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFyNh.png), however I don't know how. I wrote the code below but I don't find a way to obtain the plot. The point here is to add density lines to my original plot (Relation Masa-SFR) the density is supposed to be every 0.3 in x. I mean one line from 7 to 7.3, the next one from 7.3 to 7.6 and so on. With the code below (continue until x=12), I obtain the this [plot][2]

```
plot(SFsl$MEDMASS, SFR_SalpToMPA,xlim= range(7:12),
  ylim= range(-3:2.5),ylab="log(SFR(M(sun)/yr)",
  xlab="log(M(star)/(M(sun)")  
title("Relacion Masa-SFR")
par(new=TRUE)
FCUTsfrsl1=(SFsl$MEDMASS >= 7 & SFsl$MEDMASS <=7.3  &
  SFR_SalpToMPA < 2 & SFR_SalpToMPA > -3)
x <- SFR_SalpToMPA[FCUTsfrsl1]
y <- density(x)
plot(y$y, y$x, type='l',ylim=range(-3:2.5), col="red",
  ylab="", xlab="", axes=FALSE)
```

I did what you said but I obtained this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFyNh.png), I don't know if I did something wrong

Comment: I think both plots you linked to are the same one.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, I want the first plot, but I don't know how I can do it, I mean my density lines are starting from x=0 and I don't want that

Comment: So you want the density computed over each interval of 0.3 units?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I want. Can you please help me?

Comment: Sorry, I still need clarification.  Is the density based on the x axis values, or the y axis values?  Sample plot uses the y axis values.  Do you want to use the x values?

Comment: Yes I want to use the x values. I want y axis vs density (like an inverse or vertical plot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have your data, I had to make some up.  If this does what you want, I think you can adapt it to your actual data.

```
set.seed(7)
x <- runif(1000, 7, 12)
y <- runif(1000, -3, 3)
DF <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
plot(DF$x, DF$y)

# Cut the x axis into 0.3 unit segments, compute the density and plot
br <- seq(7, 12, 0.333)
intx <- cut(x, br) # intervals
intx2 <- as.factor(cut(x, br, labels = FALSE)) # intervals by code

intx3 <- split(x, intx) # x values
inty <- split(y, intx2) # corresponding y values for density calc

for (i in 1:length(intx3)) {
    xx <- seq(min(intx3[[i]]), max(intx3[[i]]), length.out = 512)
    lines(xx, density(inty[[i]])$y, col = "red")
    }
```

This produce the following image. You need to look closely but there is a separate density plot for each 0.3 unit interval.
[image]

**EDIT** Change the dimension that is used to compute the density

```
set.seed(7)
x <- runif(1000, 7, 12)
y <- runif(1000, -3, 3)
DF <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
plot(DF$x, DF$y, xlim = c(7, 15))

# Cut the x axis into 0.3 unit segments, compute the density and plot
br <- seq(7, 12, 0.333)
intx <- cut(x, br) # intervals
intx2 <- as.factor(cut(x, br, labels = FALSE)) # intervals by code

intx3 <- split(x, intx) # x values
inty <- split(y, intx2) # corresponding y values

# This gives the density values in the horizontal direction (desired)
# This is the change, the above is unchanged.
for (i in 1:length(intx3)) {
    yy <- seq(min(inty[[i]]), max(inty[[i]]), length.out = 512)
    offset <- min(intx3[[i]])
    lines(density(intx3[[i]])$y + offset, yy, col = "red")
    }
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! :)
I just realized that I uploaded the same plot twice, I just changed it. Would you mind taking a look at the first image? That's what I want, sorry I made a mistake

Comment: See my edit.  It's hard to get this just right with made up data, but again, you should be able to adapt the script.

Comment: I still have a problem with it. Can you please check my answer? Because I don't know how I can show you the plot that I obtain

Comment: Edit your original question and paste in the results of `dput(head(your_data))` and that way I can get a sense of what you are dealing with.  Or, if you have similar data available in a package or some public place, point me to it.

Comment: Just run the command, and paste the results into your question as an edit.  Then we can copy it and use a small piece of your data locally for troubleshooting.